# What is the best way to write the contents of a StringIO to a file?

Tags: python, file-io, stringio

What is the best way to write the contents of a `StringIO` buffer to a file ?

I currently do something like:

```
buf = StringIO()
fd = open('file.xml', 'w')
# populate buf
fd.write(buf.getvalue ())
```

But then `buf.getvalue()` would make a copy of the contents?

Comment: `StringIO` objects are always stored in main memory. If you don't want that, don't use `StringIO` and write directly to the file.

Comment: @Philipp: Yes, but using `buf.getvalue()` in this way might (?) create a copy of the contents.

Comment: @Philipp maybe programmer wants to do some operations on StringIO object before writing to file?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use [`shutil.copyfileobj`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj):

```
with open('file.xml', 'w') as fd:
  buf.seek(0)
  shutil.copyfileobj(buf, fd)
```

or `shutil.copyfileobj(buf, fd, -1)` to copy from a file object without using chunks of limited size (used to avoid uncontrolled memory consumption).

Comment: Noting that I had to run: `fd.close()`

Comment: @cooncesean: that should not be necessary when using the `with` keyword.

Answer (score 17):

Python 3:

```
from io import StringIO
...
with open('file.xml', mode='w') as f:
    print(buf.getvalue(), file=f)
```

Python 2.x:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
...
with open('file.xml', mode='w') as f:
    f.write(buf.getvalue())
```

Comment: This makes a copy of `buf.getvalue()`.

Comment: @gauteh Thanks; good point. I think this is useful for small-ish data to avoid the need for an additional import, though it strikes me as odd that `shutil.copyfileobj` is the best solution.

Comment: mode='w' is ok for text files , like the file.xml, but if the content is not text, one should write to binary with mode='wb'